# EduTools output shows incorrect solution

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm using EduTools with Android Studio to build my course, and I chose to create a task of type `output`.

My `main.kt` contains this code

```
fun main() {
    print("Hello, world!")
}
```

and my `test/output.txt` file contains only this string

```
Hello, world!
```

But when I run the solution, it gets an error
[image: incorrect output]

Any idea of where I went wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 4.2.2 supports the EduTools plugin version 2021.2.1, which is out of date. I would recommend installing [IntelliJ IDEA Edu](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea-edu/) with a built-in EduTools plugin and test your course there.